# React lazy in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-16

I've just updated my create-react-app to version 2.1.1 which adds support for typescript ([check it out](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/releases/tag/v2.1.0)).

by command `npx create-react-app my-app --typescript`, one can create a react app with typescript by default, 
but adding lazy

```
import React, { Component, lazy} from 'react';
```

cause this error

```
Type error: Module '".../node_modules/@types/react/index"' 
has no exported member 'lazy'.  TS2305
```

Probably I'm missing something here

Thanks

Comment: @lonut, maybe, but from reactks.org it seems that lazy should be available react package itself, import React, {lazy, Suspense} from 'react';  from https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/10/23/react-v-16-6.html

Comment: @Think-Twice, react version that I use is 16.6.1  ( "react": "^16.6.1",)

Comment: Looks like from the error, typescript yet to support react v16.6.0 because lazy is included in react v16.6.0. The error thrown from @types library

Comment: @Think-Twice, as I understand, I should wait for typescript support ?!!!

Comment: Yes it looks like typescript yet to support react v16.6.0

Comment: TypeDef is updated: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Long story short, You need to wait for support from @types/react maintainers.

There are the links to the corresponding issues - [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/29989) and [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/29990).

Answer (score 1):

[@types/react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react) hase been released for react v16.6 and v16.7 just upgrade @types/react to use new React type definition